# java getSuperclass().toString() not running my custom toString()

Tags: java, reflection, tostring, superclass

[*Hi, guys. I'm learning Java with Cay Horstmann's 'Java SE8 for the Really Impatient'. Studying chapter 4*]

I want to call the `toString()` method of the parent class and add something to it. Unfortunately, the call to the `toString()` method of the parent class seems not to be working.

So far I've got these classes:

```
public class Point {
    private double _x = 0;
    private double _y = 0;

    public Point(double x, double y) {
        _x=x;
        _y=y;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {

        String theString = getClass().getSuperclass().toString() + " => " + getClass().getCanonicalName();

        theString += "[";
        int i=0;
        for (Field theField : getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
            theField.setAccessible(true);
            try {
                if (i>0) theString += ", ";
                theString += theField.getName() + ": " + theField.get(this).toString();
                i++;
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Point.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                System.out.println("err1");
            } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Point.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                System.out.println("err2");
            }
        }
        theString += "]";
        return theString;
    }
    ...        
}

public class LabeledPoint extends Point {
    private String _label = "";

    public LabeledPoint(String label, double x, double y) {
        super(x, y);
        this._label = label;
    }

    ...

}
```

And I call them with this `main` method:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    LabeledPoint lp1 = new LabeledPoint("FirstPoint", 10.5, 30);
    System.out.println("The new point is:");
    System.out.println(lp1);
}
```

So, I was **expecting** to get something like this:

```
Point[_x: 10.5, _y:30.0]=>LabeledPoint[_label: FirstPoint]
```

But instead, I'm **getting** :

```
Point=>LabeledPoint[_label: FirstPoint]
```

That is, the `getClass().getSuperclass().toString()` is **not** executing `Point.toString()`, but it's just printing out the canonical name.

Why is that?

Comment: You are calling `toString()` on the `class` (not an instance).

Comment: Great! So, how do I call this instance's parent `toString()` method? I tried `super.toString()` but I got the `Object.toString()` method, that is: `LabeledPoint@7852e922=>...`

Comment: You have not shown in the code that you have overriden toString in LabeledPoint. So when you are calling toString on lp1 you are actually calling the toString of its parent class Point.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to need `super.toString()` instead of `getClass().getSuperClass().toString()`

Comment: Thanks, Codebender, but  I tried `super.toString()` but I got the `Object.toString()` method, that is: `LabeledPoint@7852e922=>...`

Comment: @JoseVelas that's because it's in the `toString()` method of `Point`, so the super class is `Object`. Did you mean to put that code in `LabeledPoint`?

Comment: @bcsb1001: If I put that code in `LabeledPoint`, then I get the same: `LabeledPoint@7852e922=>LabeledPoint[_label: FirstPoint]`. What I want to do is to use 'reflection' to not having to care about what subclass is calling the `toString()` method, it will always print out the declared fields from `Point`. That is: The fields declared in `Point` and the fields declared in `LabeledPoint`

Answer (score 0):

OK, guys. (I don't know how good this is, but it works)

The `Point` class looks like this:

```
public class Point {
    private double _x = 0;
    private double _y = 0;

    public Point(double x, double y) {
        _x=x;
        _y=y;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {

        String theString =  super.toString() + "=>" + getClass().getCanonicalName();

        //The following creates an array of fields that includes the parent 'Point's fields if the object is an instance of a direct child class of Point
        Field[] theFields;
        if (this.getClass() == Point.class) {
            theFields = getClass().getDeclaredFields();
        } else {

            theFields = new Field[Point.class.getDeclaredFields().length+getClass().getDeclaredFields().length];
            System.arraycopy(
                    Point.class.getDeclaredFields(), 
                    0, 
                    theFields, 
                    0, 
                    Point.class.getDeclaredFields().length
            );
            System.arraycopy(
                    getClass().getDeclaredFields(), 
                    0, 
                    theFields, 
                    Point.class.getDeclaredFields().length, 
                    getClass().getDeclaredFields().length
            );


        }

        theString += "[";
        int i=0;
        for (Field theField : theFields) {
            theField.setAccessible(true);
            try {
                if (i>0) theString += ", ";
                theString += theField.getName() + ": " + theField.get(this).toString();
                i++;
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Point.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                System.out.println("err1");
            } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Point.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                System.out.println("err2");
            }
        }

        theString += "]";

        return theString;
    }
    ...
}
```